# Altium trace Clearance auto finder (based on ANSI / IPC-2221/IPC-2221A standards)?

Tags: pcb, standard, autorouter, clearance

I need to make one LED PCB Bord for lighting using SO i have designed my schematic into Altium designer V16, like this (single side ):

[image]

So according ANSI / IPC-2221/IPC-2221A design standards for My PCB in some tracks i need to change the track clearance because of crossing two or more track with different voltage, So could i insert this standard in Altium and it automatically find the voltage difference betwine tracks and find proper track clearance according this standard?

If No, is there any PCB designer software which have this capability?!!!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you considered a 2 sided board? And what about a resistor for each parallel LED string?

Comment: As a side note, you have asked 14 questions and received good answers to some (most) of your questions, yet you have yet to accept any answers...

Comment: for some questions is done,dud !!!

Comment: added single side in the question body.

Comment: Just a hint, DON'T USE THE AUTOROUTER! Look at the mess you made of your PCB!

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is the ability to drop in the standard and it to automatically enter everything, I don't know of a tool that will do this for you.
However, if you understand what the standard is requiring, you can use the Design Rule checker to automatically check your design.

In your PCB Layout Editor, choose Design->Rules...  Use the Wizard to create a new Electrical -> Clearance Constraint that will alert you when two nets are too close to each other (based on the rule in the standard), or are short-circuited.  Altium should highlight nets which violate your rule.  You can also manually run the Design Rule Check by going to Tools -> Design Rule Check.

Comment: I know those rules but i am searching doing it's Automatically by Altium or other software !!!